# Showing windows (file/directory) context menu in c# winforms application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, contextmenu

I'm trying to display standard file/directory context menu in WinForms application - I'd like to enable the user to do things with files in my application as he could in Explorer.

There should be two options

- popup the context menu with some system call
- read everything from the system context menu and insert it into my context menu

Could you please point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written a .NET library to allow this. You can find it here:

http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/

The class you're looking for is ShellContextMenu within that library.

Comment: Groky that library that you created is amazing. I do not know that much about win forms so I been having a hard time trying to see how you implemented the context menu. I need to implement that in wpf. I am sure that it will be essay to implement it on wpf once I know how to do it in win forms.

Comment: Also I don't need it to look like the file dialog. I just have a container on my wpf application that displays files (icons with labels) and I will like to enable users to see the same context menu that they see when they right click on that file on windows explorer.

Comment: @TonoNam: unfortunately I didn't implement the context menu - I just used the Windows Shell API to display the context menu used by Explorer. I have no idea how you'd implement it in WPF, or even if such a thing would be possible, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

This may prove to be very challenging, so I propose two solutions:

1. **(Easy)** Using the library that Groky suggested, **do what is done in [FolderSizes](http://www.foldersizes.com).**  The Explorer context menu is shown as a sub-context-menu.  You can simulate this by displaying the explorer menu when the "Explorer Operation" item is hovered.

   [image]
2. **(Hard)** If that is insufficient, you can **go all the way and get the menu items from the shell,** and create your own menu.  This CodeProject article ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx ) goes through the process of enumerating and invoking shell commands for a specific shell object, and how to enumerate submenus.