# Display windows explorer context menu in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm working a WPF application that displays a list of files and I'd like to display the same context menu than windows explorer.

I read the thread here:
[Showing windows (file/directory) context menu in c# winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583946/showing-windows-file-directory-context-menu-in-c-sharp-winforms-application)

But I'd like to avoid going through winform host.

How I could implement such a behavior in pure C#/WPF?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing windows (file/directory) context menu in c# winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583946/showing-windows-file-directory-context-menu-in-c-sharp-winforms-application)

Comment: I had to embed a Windows Forms host  control into my WPF application, but it turns out to that using https://github.com/grokys/gong-shell was pretty straight forward. Thanks